# Keyword matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm

So I'm trying to find a way to create an algorithm that matches keywords.

So I was looking for something that works a bit like LinkedIn.

Basically a person creates an account choosing keywords from a database selecting their skills. 
Ex. "Adobe Photoshop" and then selects his/her "level of knowledge" in the specific program ranging 1-5.

And then on the other side an employer puts in a job posting selecting keywords that are relevant to the job. And the employer has the option to drag the keywords into two different categories. 
For simplicity lets call category one " Very Important" and category 2 "less important" 
Category one will be weighted with x3 and cathegory two with x1,5

Example: if Adobe Photoshop would be considered "very important" and a user has selected a 4 on Adobe Photoshop as his skill level. He/she would be awarded 12 points.

I'm trying to get as much details out as possible.

Now what kind of algorithm would be optimal for matching the keywords and then putting the users in some kind of " highscore table" presenting the best candidates for the specific posting

I hope I got all the relevant info out.

Thanks !

Comment: This is more about organizing your data than about the algorithm.
Basically, you should have 3 tables: Person, Topic, and Score. The latter is a many-to-many relationship between Person and Topic: (PersonId, TopicId, score). Then when an offer comes, a search should be made in the score table. This is a hint to start the work. As SO is not a coding service, you can ask for further help once you show your effort and face a specific problem.